# how to access dynamically generated textboxes and apply some validation

Tags: asp.net

I am generating dynamically textboxes and adding them to a placeholder as below.

```
 TextBox txt = new TextBox();

 txt.ID = "txt" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["id"].ToString();
 txt.Width = 250;
 txt.ToolTip = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["TotalMarks"].ToString();
 phMemberTextboxes.Controls.Add(txt);
 phMemberTextboxes.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("\n<br />"));
```

i want to access the values from these textboxes. and need to check if the textbox value is less than tooltip value. If so need to reset textboxes.
How can i do so?

Comment: Where you want to check and reset textbox value, at client side or at server side ?

Comment: ON server side i need to reset these textboxes.Validation i want to do on client side. If the tool tip value is greater then ok else need to show a message box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When u add dynamically generated controls to placeholder, their IDs get changed, you have to set control's ClientID first to access it at client side:

```
txt.ClientID = "txt" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["id"].ToString();
txt.Attributes.Add("onblur", string.Format("validateControl('{0}');", txt.ClientID);
```

Then in your javascript:

```
function validateControl(ctrlId){
    var txtCtrl = document.getElementById(ctrlId);
    int txtVal = txtCtrl.value;
    // Note that getAttribute doesn't work in IE 6 and requires exact property name
    var txtMarks = parseInt(txtCtrl.getAttribute("title")); 
    if (txtVal.length < txtMarks.length){
        // Reset textbox value and show the message
        txtCtrl.value = "";
        var msg = "Value must be greater than " + txtMarks;
        alert(msg);
        txtCtrl.focus();
    }
}
```

Comment: Javascript's _onblur_ is called when focus is moved away from control. In my code it resets the value if it is less than Marks, alerts the user to enter correct value and sets the focus on it.

Comment: Just added .length in your post.

Comment: It should be title while getting attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Set TextBox `onclick` Attributes.

```
YourButton.Attributes.Add("onclick", "YourJavascriptFunction('" + txt.ClientID + "');");
```

Now in YourJavascriptFunction

```
function YourJavascriptFunction(ID)
{
    var txtCtrl = document.getElementById(ctrlId);
    int txtVal = txtCtrl.value;
    // Note that getAttribute doesn't work in IE 6 and requires exact property name
    var txtMarks = parseInt(txtCtrl.getAttribute("title")); 
    if (txtVal.length < txtMarks.length){
       // Reset textbox value and show the message
       txtCtrl.value = "";
       var msg = "Value must be greater than " + txtMarks;
       alert(msg);
       txtCtrl.focus();
    }

}
```

Comment: it will check validation when i will click on textbox?

Comment: you can select any event according to your requirement.

Comment: How do you want to perform the validation? I mean on which event ?

Comment: On page submit button's click event.